# Search database while I enter data in to a text area

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a table data [Columns: id,question,answer each question have answer]; In frontend/UI  i have a textarea while i paste a question to this field which search for exact question in db and show the result. 
I want ajax no need to click any search button. I want this to work when I paste question in to the text area.

Code i am using

***HTML:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">       
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CSS3</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>PHP5</h1>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">

         <input size="100" type="text" id="searchid"  class="form-control" rows="10" cols="100" />
      </div>

     <div id="resultdiv"></div>
    </form>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- /container -->
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
      </body>
    </html>
```

***jQuery:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#searchid').keydown(function (e){ // Event for enter keydown.

            if(e.keyCode == 13){

            var idvalue = $("#searchid").val(); // Input value.

                $.ajax({ //Ajax call.

                    type: "GET",
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: 'id=' + idvalue , 
                    type: 'json',
                    success: function(msg){
                        // Show results in textareas.
                        msg = JSON.parse( msg );  // Line added 

                        alert (msg);

                         $('#resultdiv').val(msg.answer);

                        }

                    }); // Ajax Call
                } //If statement

        }); //document.ready
    </script>
```

**My Search.php**

```
      <?php

     if ($_GET['id']):   

        $dataid = json_decode($_GET['id']);


        // Connect to database.
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); 
        mysqli_select_db ($con,'exam_css3'); 

        // Get the values from the table.
        $sql = "SELECT answer FROM exam_css3 where question LIKE '$dataid' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {   
        $answer = $row[answer]; 

        }

    $rows = array('answer' => $answer); 

    echo json_encode($rows);

    endif;

    ?>
```

This code is not working, can anyone help on this?

Comment: anything in console?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
localhost/:49 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: What does 'not working at all' mean? Do you get an error? Does the search fail? If the latter, notice that you search for `LIKE '$dataid'`, not `LIKE '%{$dataid}%'`, so you need to enter **the full and exact text of the question** for it to work. A single phrase in the question **will not work**.

Comment: @BANNA: for that issue, try including jQuery *before* bootstrap.

Comment: I corrected that. But i don't see any result while i paste or type question

Answer (score 1):

There are, among other things, some issues in your PHP.

First of all you search for `$dataid`, which means an exact match. You need to do

```
"SELECT answer FROM exam_css3 where question LIKE '%{$dataid}' ";
```

Then you always save *only one* answer, and you do not specify quote marks around 'answer', which might cause a PHP warning, which would corrupt the JSON output:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {   
        $answer = $row[answer]; 
    }
    $rows = array('answer' => $answer); 

   echo json_encode($rows);

endif;
```

So you might want to rewrite that as

```
<?php

if (array_key_exists('id', $_GET)) {

    $dataid = json_decode($_GET['id']);
    // Here it would be good to check whether the decoding succeeded.
    // I'd also try doing in HTML:   data: { id: idvalue }

    // Connect to database.
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
    mysqli_select_db ($con,'exam_css3'); 

    // Get the values from the table.
    // Only interested in one match.
    $sql = "SELECT answer FROM exam_css3 where question LIKE '%{$dataid}%' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    $answer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (null === $answer) {
        $answer = array('answer' => 'nothing found', 'status' => 'error');
    }

    // Since we're putting this into HTML...
    $answer['answer'] = HTMLspecialChars($answer['answer']);

} else {
    $answer = array('answer' => 'no query was supplied', 'status' => 'error');
}
Header ('Content-Type: application/json');
die(json_encode($answer));
```

In the code above I have added a 'status' variable so that in the jQuery you can do

```
if (msg.error) {
    alert("Error: " + msg.answer);
    return;
}
```

and further differentiate between correct and incorrect answers.

Other issues exist (for example you ought to use PDO and switch to prepared queries; as things stand, if the question contains a quote sign such as

```
What's a SQL injection?
```

your SQL search would throw an error. *This is not limited to SQL injection*. **NO QUERY CONTAINING QUOTE MARKS WILL WORK**. You need at least to [escape the string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) dataid before placing it in the query.

Comment: Thank you. SQL injection not a big issues in my case since it a local pc usage. I changed the codes as per your suggestions. What changes i have to make in my mail index.php file i dont see result yet.

Comment: this error i have in console Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in D:\wamp\www\exam\search.php on line 24

Comment: You have probably a control structure which has been left open. I'd also suggest not using the "if ... : / endif" construct but curly braces. Modifying answer...

Comment: With the edited code i am getting this error. {"answer":"no query was supplied","status":"error"}

Comment: This means that the jQuery is **not** sending a "id=" parameter. I had feared as much. You'll find a comment to that effect in the code, on how to modify the jQuery call. In a pinch, you can also *not* supply the `data` parameter and add `'?url'+idvalue` to the `url` parameter. Not very elegant, but it ought to work.

Comment: Thanks. I almost did it now only issues is that . If my answrd contain codes like the json [{"answer":"<?php include:\"time.inc\"; ?>","0":"<?php include:\"time.inc\"; ?>"}] i can not print it is not showing in my div success: function(result) {
             $.each(result, function(i, v) {
                 // For each record in the returned array
                 $('#resultdiv').html(v.answer); 
             });
         }

                    }); // Ajax Call

Comment: Hm. You need to transform the code in something that won't crash your existing HTML code. Have you tried `htmlspecialchars`, or even `htmlentities` (see updated code)?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining twice the `type` in your ajax. `json` is the `dataType` not simple the `type`. `type` is get, what you do not need to set, that is the default.

The second problem is, you pass your data as a string, not as a json object, so on your server side, that will be an array, what you can not `json_decode`.

Comment: He *is* passing data as a JSON. On *some* browsers this will work (and that's why we find such 'tutorials' on the net). To work in all (well... *most*) browsers he would need to add `Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');` before sending the result from `json_encode`.